# how to group in two tables in SQl server?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following issue :

table # 1 structure :

Requests table for example have 2 columns :

Request_ID          Branch_Name

```
1                  xx 
2                  yy
3                  xx
4                  xx
5                  yy
```

The second table : Requests_Items  for example have the following columns

```
Request_ID      Price  

1               100   
1               30
1               450
2               10
2               18
```

So i want my result set to be like :

```
 Branch Name     Num_of_Requests     Total_Price 

    xx                 3               580
```

Can you please help

Comment: You want to know how many requests each branch had?

Comment: Not sure why I can't edit my comment, but show us what you're actually getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select r.Branch_Name, 
       count(r.request_id) as Num_of_Requests, 
       sum(i.price) as Total_Price 
from Requests r
left join Requests_Items i on i.Request_ID = r.Request_ID  
group by r.Branch_Name
```

Comment: thank you for fast response . but after test i found that the Num_of_requests is the number of items in the second table ... so i need the Num_of_requests from the first table for the same branch name

Comment: i got same result ! nothing changed .. request_id is primary key ? so its correct to count it ? anyways i tried to use r.request_id and r.Branch_Name ... but the num_of_requests doesnt change .

Comment: You need to change `count(r.request_id)` to `count(i.price)` (or any other column in the Requests_Items table.

Comment: @user1535202: It should work. See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a685/1).

Answer (score 0):

jurgen d was almost there

```
select      r.Request_Id, r.Branch_Name,
            COUNT(i.Price) as [Number of Requests],
            SUM(i.Price) as [Total]
from        Requests r
left join   Requests_Items i
on          r.Request_Id = i.Request_Id
group by    r.Request_Id, r.Branch_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.Branch_Name, COUNT(ri.Request_ID) as Num_of_Requests, SUM(ri.Price) as Total_Price
from dbo.Requests r
left join dbo.Requests_Items ri
on r.Request_ID = ri.Request_ID
group by r.Branch_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Let this is my **[Employees**] Table

[image]

Here is my **Dept** table

[image]

I want the output like this using **join and group by**

[image]

So here is the Query for this-

```
select max(e.salary) as maxsalary,d.Dept from Employees e inner join DEpt d on e.DeptId=d.id group by e.DeptId,d.Dept
    enter code here
```